# How to hide and show table tree row using Angular 5 directives

Tags: javascript, html

Just need the table tree by clicking on the row which needs to hide and show using angular 5. The following code will highlight the row. I have tried a lot of solutions. Please help me to hide the table tree and show child rows. The table tree structure is as follows :parent rows:1 ,2 ,3 ,4-this needs to display initially. Then by clicking on the parent 1 row it should display the child of 1.1,1.2.

```js
import {
  Directive,
  Renderer2,
  OnInit,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  HostBinding,
  Input
} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appBetterHighlight]'
})
export class BetterHighlightDirective implements OnInit {
 
  
  @HostBinding('style.backgroundColor') backgroundColor: string;

  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.backgroundColor = this.defaultColor;
    // this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseenter') mouseover(eventData: Event) {
    // this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'blue');
    this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave') mouseleave(eventData: Event) {
    // this.renderer.setStyle(this.elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'transparent');
    this.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>one</th>
<th>two</th>
<th>three</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody >
<tr *ngFor="let demo of demoData" appBetterHighlight>
<td>{{demo.one}}</td>
<td>{{demo.two}}</td>
<td>{{demo.three}}</td>
</tr> 
<tr *ngFor="let demo of demoData" [style.display]="'none'" appBetterHighlight>
<td>{{demo.one}}</td>
<td>{{demo.two}}</td>
<td>{{demo.three}}</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you essentially going for an accordion-menu?

Comment: Yes Claymore.I am looking for accordion-menu with table tree row

Comment: Yes Claymore......

Comment: I do know they have native support for this: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/, but it doesn't look like it uses tables, at least at the top-level.  You could conceivably just put individual smaller tables inside the wrappers that it's expecting though.  If you want something with more complexity to it though, you might want to look into Kendo Grids: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/

Comment: this link is for angular.js it is a lower version. iam working on angular 6,.

Comment: telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid this one i hava not required. i need of custom directive in angular 5